# pack two columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a two column matrix. How do I pack the columns into a pair/tuple so that they can be assigned to a one column matrix?

```
> A = matrix(NA,nrow=5,ncol=1)
> B = matrix(runif(10),ncol=2)
> A
     [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA
[3,]   NA
[4,]   NA
[5,]   NA

> B
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.1886287 0.6995596
[2,] 0.1576875 0.9792369
[3,] 0.9056386 0.1640904
[4,] 0.9125812 0.7003167
[5,] 0.9327778 0.8149431

> A[,1] = B   # need this to work
```

I have a n-col matrix of prices, a column for each stock. I am trying to compute a moving MACD statistic for each stock. I am using a n-col MACD matrix to contain the results. When I feed a one col of prices to MACD function (from package TTR), it returns a 2-col matrix of signal and macd, so I need to way to contain this statistic within the same dimension.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If you tell us what you want to do, we might be able to suggest alternatives, e.g. lists of matrices...

Comment: Revised question to provide more context. thanks

Comment: Actually I could just make my MACD matrix have 2n cols and reference them accordingly later. This is probably a cleaner solution and more efficient than the ones given below. What do you think?

Comment: The `signal` column is just a moving average of `macd` column, so you could put `macd` in a m-by-n matrix and recalculate `signal` if you need it.  What are you planning to do with the results from `MACD`?

Comment: No I need to 'prefetch' these statistics for some backtesting. Running EMA later would be cumbersome in my current framework.

Comment: Another option for me is to just maintain two separate matrices of 'signal' and 'macd'. this should work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with lists.

```
> matrix(apply(B,1,list))
     [,1]  
[1,] List,1
[2,] List,1
[3,] List,1
[4,] List,1
[5,] List,1
```

That said, this is a very un-R-like way to do things and is probably more trouble than it's worth.  If you describe what you're actually trying to do, someone could show you a more appropriate approach.

UPDATE:
Based on the updated question, the code below will put the `macd` and `signal` in a 2n matrix.  You may want to write a more elaborate function (e.g. one that identifies the `macd` and `signal` columns with their respective instruments).

If you want the `macd` and `signal` columns in separate matrices, you could just `grep` the columns from the `out` object.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY;IWM;QQQ")
Data <- Cl(merge(SPY,IWM,QQQ))
out <- do.call(merge, lapply(1:NCOL(Data), function(i) MACD(Data[,i])))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then:

```
A[,1] = paste(B[,1], B[,2])
```

However, the elements of `A` are characters, not vectors. In a matrix, each element must be a single value. So this is almost certainly not what you want.

There are two other options:

1. A list (see Joshua's answer)
2. An array

but we need more details to give you a proper answer.